# Function to get the length of the longest string

Tags: python, string, python-3.4

I want to define a function that will get the length of the longest string in a variable.
I do the below, using the `*` before strings so that it includes all arguments.

But when I test my function, it only gives the length of the first string (instead of giving me the longest). What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> def longlen(*strings):
    max=0
    for s in strings:
        if len(s)>max:
            max=len(s)
            return(max)
>>> longlen('kodak','polaroid','sony')
5
```

Comment: What do you think will happen after the function `return`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is a programming task, getting you in touch with functions and stuff. But you do not need a for loop here, this can be done with much faster list comprehension. If you are interested in that solution, here it comes:

```
def longlen(*strings):
    return max([len(s) for s in strings])
```

Comment: You don't need to make it a list comprehension; `max` will take a generator expression as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, in a real world use case you'd use:

```
max_len = max(map(len, strings))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the indentation of the return statement. Your code will always return the first length, it will never iterate for all the subsequent strings.

```
def longlen(*strings):
    max=0
    for s in strings:
        if len(s)>max:
            max=len(s)
    return(max)
```

Comment: True, your identation is not correct. But I got the idea and got it right. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: The `return` is now in the right place, the `def` still isn't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I know, but I assume that OP knows that too because maybe of the copy/paste, the error was only only in the return statement.

Comment: No, it appears like that in the question because it's copied from IDLE, where the prompt takes four characters. Include the prompt or or don't, but the rest of the function should be indented further.

Answer (score 0):

return your max after the completion of for loop

```
def longlen(*strings):
    max=0
    for s in strings:
        if len(s)>max:
            max=len(s) 
    return(max)
print longlen('kodak','polaroid','sony')
```

Output:8

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is not correct. See [documentation on python indentation](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html).

```
   def longlen(*strings):
maximum=0
for s in strings:
    if len(s)>maximum:
        maximum=len(s)
return(maximum)
```